# Insufficient Privileges: Execute a procedure in packages and creating dynamic view

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

i have two user schemas.
 Let's Say A & B.
 A has a procedure written in it SAY 'XProc'.

B has a package which has Procedure say 'B_Pack_Proc', which creates a dynamic view in B user schema.

The B_pack_proc creates view in B schema itself.

but i am executing the B_Pack_Pro from A, i am getting error insufficient privileges.

I am using oracle forms 11g and oracle DB 11g.

i have granted explicit grants to User A from User B
 i.e Create any view
 Execute on view.
execute on package_name

please help.

-
 Prathamesh

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with invoker's rights vs. definer's rights.

If the package B.Some_Package.B_Pack_Proc is created with `authid current_user`, then it will only work if A has been granted select on B.dynamic_view.  If the package is created with `authid definer`, the default, then B.Some_Package.B_Pack_Proc should have privilege on any object owned by B and you only need to grant execute on that package to A.